# Using glDrawElements with uniform?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently using `glDrawElements` to send a bunch of vertices for the GPU to render. The problem that I have now, is that I'd like to assign a value to an uniform (called `material`) for each vertex, so it can be used in a vertex shader. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Uniform values are uniform for a whole draw call (hence the name) - and the cannot in princple be changed between the vertices of a single primitive. For per-vertex values, you have to use attributes. GL guarantees that there are at least 16 generic attributs, each up to a `vec4`. If that is not enoguh, you can use some attribute (or the `gl_VertexID` builtin) to index into a *texture buffer object* (or a standard texture).

Comment: Alright, I'm using `glVertexAttribPointer`, how do I access its value in a shader?

Comment: @M28: have a look at [this wiki entry](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Attributes). This is a very basic concept of GL, you should learn the basics first.